# build workflow engine with Akka

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, activiti, camunda

In our Scala/Play application we use [activiti](http://activiti.org/). (also experimenting with [camunda](http://camunda.com/)) users can create workflows (shown in this picture http://camunda.com/ ). All calls to these external workflow engines are wrapped in Scala [Future](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future) (activiti and camunda APIs are all Java blocking APIs).

is there any library to implement workflows totally using Akka/Actors avoiding heavy toolkits like activiti/camunda? Or ideas how to best use Akka with activiti/camunda ?

Comment: How did you resolve the issue? Which one did you take at last? I have the same problem now.

Answer (score 4):

You could try and use the Akka FSM dsl to do the same bypassing activity and also blocking apis. see http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/fsm.html

Comment: Well, Akka FSM can be a good fit for implementing "static" workflows where you are aware of state machine upfront. Activiti/camunda allows you to create workflows/process definitions on the fly and users can change workflow on dynamically etc. Is there a way to create FSM dynamically similar to activiti/camunda/jbpm?

Answer (score 4):

Note that camunda has very [powerful asynchronous continuation features](http://docs.camunda.org/latest/guides/user-guide/#process-engine-transactions-in-processes-asynchronous-continuations) which allow you to delegate any long-running processing to background threads. This allows very flexible configuration of "how much work" is done synchronously in the client (possibly HTTP) thread. This can give you a good balance between performance and fault tolerance.

Answer (score 3):

I know of the existence of the [Catify BPMN Engine](https://github.com/catify/bpmn-engine), built using Akka (Java). I do not have any experience with it, nor do I know for sure whether API calls are asynchronous, but I would expect so. Since it is written in Akka it should combine well with Play!.